# VS Add-in to open a solution

Tags: visual-studio-2010, add-in

I am writing Visual Studio 2010 add-in. Purpose of this add in is to show all the VS solutions from a particular folder. We have around 100 solutions under our trunk folder. After add-in explore the folder and listed out solutions, developer would click any one of those solution to open it in same VS window. I have already a created a windows form in C# to list the solutions. Now I need to write a code to open the selected solution into the same VS window. I am not expert in Add-in writing. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [Solution Load Manager extension](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/66350dbe-ed01-4120-bea2-5564eff7b0b2).  [Source code available here](http://code.google.com/p/solutionloadmanager/).

Comment: I appreciate it. Solution manager is how and when to load project in a solution. But question I asked before opening solution itself, developer should be able to see the list of solutions in a particular folder and load the one he chooses. Moreover I could not open solution in source code folder of SolutionManger.